# Reassign Pandas DataFrame column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv that has incorrect datetime formatting. I've worked out how to convert those values into the format I need, but now I need to reassign all the values in a column to the new, converted values.

For example, I'm hoping that there's something I can put into the following FOR loop that will insert the values back into the dataframe at the correct location:

```
for i in df[df.columns[1]]:
    t = pd.Timestamp(i)
    short_date = t.date().strftime('%m/%d/%Y').lstrip('0')   
    # Insert back into dataframe?
```

As always, your help is very much appreciated!

Part of the column in question:
Part of the dataframe in question:

```
Created Date    
2019-02-27 22:55:16    
2019-01-29 22:57:12    
2018-11-29 00:13:31    
2019-01-30 21:35:15
2018-12-20 21:14:45    
2018-11-01 16:20:15    
2019-04-11 16:38:07    
2019-01-24 00:23:17    
2018-12-21 19:30:10    
2018-12-19 22:33:04    
2018-11-07 19:54:19    
2019-05-10 21:15:00
```

Comment: I have the feeling you don't need to do `for` loop here. Something like `df.iloc[:,1] = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:,1])` would work.

Comment: Also, please give example of dataset to show what you are trying to do.

Comment: just like `df['columnname'] = pd.to_datetime(df['columnname'].lstrip('0'), format='%m/%d/%Y')`

Comment: You really don't want to iterate over values in a column like in pandas because it takes away vectorization. There is nearly always a better way!

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest, but most instructive, possible terms:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 5, 6]})
df
#    x  y
# 0  1  4
# 1  2  5
# 2  3  6

df[:] = df[:].astype(float)
df
#      x    y
# 0  1.0  4.0
# 1  2.0  5.0
# 2  3.0  6.0
```

Let `pandas` do the work for you.

Or, for only one column:

```py
df.x = df.x.astype(float)
df
#      x  y
# 0  1.0  4
# 1  2.0  5
# 2  3.0  6
```

You'll, of course, replace `astype(float)` with `.date().strftime('%m/%d/%Y').lstrip('0')`.

Answer (score 1):

To reassign a column, no need for a loop.  Something like this should work:

```
df["column"] = new_column
```

`new_column` is either a `Series` of matching length, or something that can be broadcasted<sup>1</sup> to that length.  You can find more details in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html).

That said, if `pd.Timestamp` can already parse your data, there is no need for "formatting".  The formatting is not associated with a timestamp instance.  You can choose a particular formatting when you are converting to string with something like `df["timestamp"].dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")`.

On the other hand, if you want to change the precision of your timestamp, you can do something like this:

```
df["timestamp"] = df["timestamp"].astype("datetime64[D]")
```

Here, all time information will be rounded to a resolution of days.  The letter between the `[` and `]` is the resolution.  Again, all this and more is discussed in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html).

---

<sup>1</sup> Broadcasting is a concept from `numpy` where you can operate between different but compatibly shaped arrays.  Again, everything is covered in the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. All of the answers were helpful, but the answer I ended up using was as follows:

```
import pandas as pd 

df[df.columns[0]] = pd.to_datetime(df[df.columns[0]]).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```